# Is there any Java Look and Feel implementation using only console?

Tags: java, swing, console, look-and-feel

I would like to run an simple Java GUI application on a system without GUI.

Changing the LaF to a console-based (even partial) implementation would make it possible, but so far I could not find any.

Comment: Interesting question. You mean like the text based UIs that late 80-ties/early 90-ties DOS apps had? I don't think there is such a thing in Java. Those DOS based things surely seemed to following some kind of LAF though, as many of those had a similar look.

Comment: Just to be certain, are you saying that you wish to run this text-based GUI in a headless environment (i.e. a pure console-only solution on a machine without a window manager)?

Answer (score 2):

There is [TUIAWT](http://www.bmsi.com/tuipeer/) - it's rather old, and it's for AWT rather than Swing, but it may well do what you want.

Comment: Top fact: curses was developed to support rogue!

Comment: Nice one! Although this does require to go back to Java 1.x! This excludes using almost each and evert existing library our there and means you have to fall back on the very small library that JDK 1.x provided (and deal with a lot of of its quirks).

Comment: That's a really nice find there, and ever so retro, but sadly anything that uses AWT will not work at all in a headless environment, which is what I believe the OP intends to use.

Answer (score 1):

Following links on the [TUIAWT](http://www.bmsi.com/tuipeer/) site I found [CHARVA](http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/index.html) which seems to be able to replace AWT and Swing. Not exactly only a LaF implementation, but it could be modified to provide one and in it's current state it allows developing console based UI for Java applications.

Comment: Replacing only a Swing look-and-feel would not be enough, as Swing is based on AWT (using Components, Containers, Windows and such), and so needs a Toolkit implementation to be based on.